# Google Charts - How to make 1 line for each distinct value of a list object property

Tags: c#, json, charts, google-visualization

Using C#. Passing to mvc controller List of objects which has elements & element properties like:

```
List<anobject> listOfAnobjects = new List<anobject>();

anobject1.date = 1/1/21 | anobject1.linename = "Line1" | anobject1.value = 100
anobject1.date = 1/2/21 | anobject1.linename = "Line1" | anobject1.value = 200
anobject1.date = 1/3/21 | anobject1.linename = "Line1" | anobject1.value = 300

anobject2.date = 1/2/21 | anobject2.linename = "Line2" | anobject2.value = 20
anobject2.date = 1/3/21 | anobject2.linename = "Line2" | anobject2.value = 50
anobject2.date = 1/4/21 | anobject2.linename = "Line2" | anobject2.value = 200
anobject2.date = 1/5/21 | anobject2.linename = "Line2" | anobject2.value = 120
```

---

In controller: passing listOfAnobjects list to Google Charts thru

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
 return Json(listOfAnobjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

In my Index.cshtml, I produce Google chart thru below code.
Current code produces ONE line, which has all the anobject .date / .value 's.
**How do I change so code produces 1 line chart (x,y) = (.date,.value) for EACH distinct .linename in the listOfAnobjects list.  Thank you!**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart','table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
 var dataJson;
 $.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("GetData"),
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  cache: false,
  data; {},
  success: function (dataJson) {
    var arrOutside = new Array();

    var heading = ["Date", "Value"];
    arrOutside[0] = heading;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataJson.length, i++){
     var arr = [dataJson[i].date, dataJson[i].value];
     arrOutside[i+1] = arr;
    }

    var options = {
     width: 900,
     height: 600,
    }

    var gdata = new.google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrOutside);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart1');
    chart.draw(gdata, options);
  }
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: check [this question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59586159/5090771), replace "team" with "line"...

Comment: Hi, thank you for response.  I wasn't able to follow your linked example.  To be clear, I don't know what is in the objectlist .linename (what distinct items there are).  But need a loop to be able to figure out to make a separate line for each .linename (date / value).  Can you help me a bit of a newbie a bit more in my code?  Thank youuuu.

Answer (score 0):

to draw multiple lines, one for each line name, we need a column in the data table for each.

e.g.

```
'date', 'line 1', 'line 2', ...
```

start by adding a linename column to the data table...

```
// add linename to data table
var arrOutside = [
  ['Date', 'Line', 'Value']
];
dataJson.forEach(function (row) {
  arrOutside.push([row.date, row.linename, row.value]);
});
var gdata = new.google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrOutside);
```

then we will group the data, to sum the values by linename...

```
// group data table by linename
var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
  gdata,
  [0, 1],
  [{
    column: 2,
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
    type: 'number'
  }]
);
```

next, we create a data view, to separate each linename into its own column in the data table.

```
// create data view from grouped data
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(groupData);

// sum column array
var aggColumns = [];

// use date as first view column
var viewColumns = [0];

// build view & agg columns for each linename
groupData.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (linename, index) {
  // add view column for each linename
  viewColumns.push({
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === linename) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 2);
      }
      return null;
    },
    label: linename,
    type: 'number'
  });

  // add sum column for each linename
  aggColumns.push({
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
    column: index + 1,
    label: linename,
    type: 'number'
  });
});

// set view columns
view.setColumns(viewColumns);
```

finally, we group the data again, to sum each linename column...

```
// sum view by date
var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
  view,
  [0],
  aggColumns
);
```

then we can draw the chart with the last grouped data...

```
// draw chart
chart.draw(aggData, options);
```

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
}).then(function drawChart() {
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_chart1');
  var options = {
    width: 900,
    height: 600
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetData"),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    cache: false,
    data: {}
  }).done(function (dataJson) {
    // add linename to data table
    var arrOutside = [
      ['Date', 'Line', 'Value']
    ];
    dataJson.forEach(function (row) {
      arrOutside.push([row.date, row.linename, row.value]);
    });
    var gdata = new.google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrOutside);

    // group data table by linename
    var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
      gdata,
      [0, 1],
      [{
        column: 2,
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        type: 'number'
      }]
    );

    // create data view from grouped data
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(groupData);

    // sum column array
    var aggColumns = [];

    // use date as first view column
    var viewColumns = [0];

    // build view & agg columns for each linename
    groupData.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (linename, index) {
      // add view column for each linename
      viewColumns.push({
        calc: function (dt, row) {
          if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === linename) {
            return dt.getValue(row, 2);
          }
          return null;
        },
        label: linename,
        type: 'number'
      });

      // add sum column for each linename
      aggColumns.push({
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        column: index + 1,
        label: linename,
        type: 'number'
      });
    });

    // set view columns
    view.setColumns(viewColumns);

    // sum view by date
    var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
      view,
      [0],
      aggColumns
    );

    // draw chart
    chart.draw(aggData, options);
  });
});
```